# How to send Cypress POST request properly?

Tags: cypress

I need to create an entity by sending a POST request. While doing this manually I can see the request URL, content-type, payload, etc. E.g.:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: 'admin/xxx/manual-enrol'
Form Data: addedUserIds[]: 111
```

I have created the request which is sent successfully (returned status is 200) but the entity is not created. Here is what I have tried:

variant 1:

```
cy.request('POST', 'admin/xxx/manual-enrol', { "addedUserIds[]": 111} );
```

variant 2:

```
cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'admin/xxx/manual-enrol',
    form: true,
    body: {
      "addedUserIds[]": 111
    }
  })
```

What could be the possible reason of this failure?

Comment: hey @vitaliy4us, at first sight it is quite strange you got 200 without any auth option in your request. Maybe your app doesn't have any authentication, but in case it has, make sure you provide it in the request body. Also, if you say it returned 200, remember `cy.request()` yields the response as an object that contains properties such as body, headers and other as well. Could you check your response body/or assign it to the question for further investigations?

Comment: Is baseURL mentioned under `cypress.json` file?

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for your answers. Actually, the request is a part of the test suite. Authorization is made in "before" hook. Any other request can be performed successfully. But this one is something. I believe that the reason is a key name containing squire brackets. The returned body contains html code of the page  having information that the user was not selected which is an evidence of the bad request  But the request status is OK and no error is returned. Anyway never mind, I used another way using another request for another user but for this test it is enough for me. Thank you!